# Pyspark Lag function returning null

Tags: pyspark, window-functions, lag

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
>>> df.show()
+----------------------+------------------------+--------------------+
|date_cast             |id                      |         status    |
+----------------------+------------------------+--------------------+
|            2021-02-20|    123...              |open                |
|            2021-02-21|    123...              |open                |
|            2021-02-17|    123...              |closed              |
|            2021-02-22|    123...              |open                |
|            2021-02-19|    123...              |open                |
|            2021-02-18|    123...              |closed              |
+----------------------+------------------------+--------------------+
```

I have been trying to apply a very simple lag on to it to see what its previous day status was but I keep getting null. The date was a string so I casted, thinking maybe that is the issue due to date not ordering in results.  I also have hard coded the windowing in my over partition by and still get null.

```
df_lag = df.withColumn('lag_status',F.lag(df['status']) \
                                 .over(Window.partitionBy("date_cast").orderBy(F.asc('date_cast')))).show()
```

Can someone help with any issues below?

```
>>> column_list = ["date_cast","id"]
>>> win_spec = Window.partitionBy([F.col(x) for x in column_list]).orderBy(F.asc('date_cast'))
>>> df.withColumn('lag_status', F.lag('status').over(
...     win_spec
...     )
... )

+----------------------+------------------------+--------------------+-----------+
|date_cast             |id.                      |         staus      |lag_status|
+----------------------+------------------------+--------------------+-----------+
|            2021-02-19|    123...              |open                |       null|
|            2021-02-21|    123...              |open                |       null|
|            2021-02-17|    123...              |open                |       null|
|            2021-02-18|    123...              |open                |       null|
|            2021-02-22|    123...              |open                |       null|
|            2021-02-20|    123...              |open                |       null|
+----------------------+------------------------+--------------------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happend because You have partitioned data by date_cast and **date_cast** have unique values. Use "**id**" instead **date_cast** for example:

```
df_lag = df.withColumn('lag_status',F.lag(df['status']) \
                                 .over(Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy(F.asc('date_cast')))).show()
```